# My mail php does not work after changing htaccess url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, email

My mail php does not work after changing htaccess url and I am new to php and htaccess, cannot figure out what is wrong. Can anyone help?

index.html

```
`  <form method="post" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
```

mail.php

```
`<?php
  // Check for empty fields
  if(empty($_POST['name'])          ||
  empty($_POST['email'])        ||
  empty($_POST['phone'])        ||
  empty($_POST['message'])  ||
  !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
  }

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email_address = $_POST['email'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];


  $to = 'jondmk@jondmk.com'; 
  $email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
  $email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
  $headers = "From: noreply@jondmk.com\n"; 
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
  return true;          
  ?>
```

.htaccess

```
`ErrorDocument 404 /filenotfound.html

 IndexIgnore * 

 RewriteEngine On


 RewriteRule ^home index.html [NC,L]

 RewriteRule ^education about.html [NC,L]

 RewriteRule ^work project.html [NC,L]

 RewriteRule ^my_blog blog/blog.html [NC,L]

 RewriteRule ^about_me blog/about.html [NC,L]

 RewriteRule ^contact_me blog/contact.html [NC,L]
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What happens when you remove your htaccess file? Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML form is not POSTing to the proper file. You should specify the file to POST to, in your case it'd be mail.php

Change your beginning form tag to

```
<form method="post" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" action="mail.php" novalidate>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i tried and still not working is there any other suggestion??

Comment: Can you please specify a bit more information? What exactly isn't working? What happens when you submit the form?

Comment: When I try to send a message thru my contact form, it is saying that my mail server is not responding. It was working earlyer but right after I changed my htaccess for pretty url, my contact stoped working.    jondmk.com is the website.